# How would I be able to store these first names and last names in database automatically?

Tags: python, django

I’m currently teaching myself `Django` and I want to know how to store first names and last names in a database in its appropriate column.  I’m familiar with the `SQL` commands. I know how to manually store them in the database with the `SQL` commands using the code in the `models.py` file but this time, I want these first names and last names stored in the database upon the user hitting `Submit` after filling out the text fields so that next time when I manually look up what’s inside my database, I’ll see what the user has submitted.

How would I go about starting this?

Here's my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # /music/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # /music/71
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail),
]
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('music/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())

def detail(request, user_id): # Testing out page 2
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Page # (testing this out) " + str(user_id) + "</h2>")
```

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>The Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" name="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lastName">
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me</label></div></br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + ' - ' + self.lastName

class UI(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You can do this via javascript, add an onClick event to your Submit button.  This button sends the appropriate information back to your server, and your server at that POST request runs the code in your models.py to persist the data in your db

Comment: @touchmyboomboom I have no idea why you've confused things by bringing in JS here; there is no need for it at all.

Comment: @bojack the answer is in part 4 of the Django tutorial, which tells you how to use forms.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the view somewhat like this,

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('firstName')
        last_name = request.POST.get('lastName')
        if first_name and last_name:
            user = User.objects.create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        else:
            return Httpresponse('Not Done!')
    return render(request, 'music/index.html')
```